# Match text followed by optional pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a regex that matches a string followed by an optional pattern.

Here's an example of three input strings where I want to match `match/string`

```
/any/path/match/string
/any/path/match/string/pattern
/any/path/match/string/pattern/something/else
```

Where `/any/path` and `/pattern` is static text and `match/string` could be any text.

I have tried this

```
print $1 if m,/any/path/(.+)(?=/pattern/)?,
```

but it matches the whole input string since `.+` is greedy.

Comment: Syntax like `(?=...)?` is a no-op. Well... "*followed by an optional pattern*", does not make much sense. What are you trying to do? Please give specific examples.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to match the text between "/any/path" and "/pattern" where "/pattern" could be either present or not in the input string.

Comment: The problem is that, since `match/string` could be *"any text"* then one of the things it could be is `/match/string/pattern/something/else`. If you define properly what you want to do then the code will be much more obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already surmised, your problem is greedy matching.

Remember, if you're having trouble with a regex, you can always break the logic into steps:

```
print +(split m{/pattern\b}, $1)[0] if m{^/any/path/(.+)};
```

To do this using a single regex though, there are two approaches:

1. Limit what the any character `.` can match by putting a negative lookahead assertion before it.
2. Use non-greedy matching with an ending boundary coundition.

The following demonstrates both these methods:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print "\nString = $_";

    if (m{^/any/path/( (?:(?!/pattern\b).)* )}x) {
        print "  Neg Lookahead        - $1\n"
    }

    if (m{^/any/path/(.*?)(?:/pattern\b|$)}x) {
        print "  Nongreedy with bound - $1\n"
    }
}
__DATA__
/any/path/match/string
/any/path/match/string/pattern
/any/path/match/string/pattern/something/else
```

Outputs:

```
String = /any/path/match/string
  Neg Lookahead        - match/string
  Nongreedy with bound - match/string

String = /any/path/match/string/pattern
  Neg Lookahead        - match/string
  Nongreedy with bound - match/string

String = /any/path/match/string/pattern/something/else
  Neg Lookahead        - match/string
  Nongreedy with bound - match/string
```

Comment: `print +(split m{/pattern\b}, $1)[0] if m{^/any/path/(.+)}`? I don't know what that does!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/any/path/(\w+?/\w+)/pattern|/any/path/(\w+?/\w+)$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pZ1xO0/3)**

[image]